# Does anyone know how to code this situation? it is for the calculation of game high score

Tags: android

Does anyone knows how to code this?

Here is the game description:

3 images is displayed at the screen. The user have to put the images on the right positions. When the images are dragged to the correct positions, then the game is finished.

Now my question is, how can i write code for calculating the score and the total score. The total score will be the high score.

Help me please, I can't post my image that's why I write in words, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We'd like to help, but it is difficult to know what you're asking. Please consider rewording your question, including details of what you've considered / tried and what problems there were with your approach.

Comment: This is not a real question. How do you want to calculate the high score? Is the question about how you should display it? Also do some research and post code of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I understand from your question

> > 1.) Find number of moves n required to finish game correctly
> >
> > 2.) Assign points to each move and rank based on lowest number of moves. (3 moves -3 points, 4 moves - 4 points etc so 3 moves is better
> >     ranked than 4 moves)

I think this is better for such a game than having high scores.

> But the same logic can be used for high scores as well.  (N moves
>   where N is best moves possible - 100 points, for every extra move 10 points less and so on)

We could do with more explanation of the game.